# Неправильное отображение

Tags: php, yii2

Делаю бэкэнд в приложении на yii2-advanced, очистил кэш и теперь вместо страницы индекса в бэкэнде отображается файл конфига.
Как исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием минимальной программы для воспроизведения проблемы до публикации вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

оказалось что в файле config/main.php не было начала `<?php`